# WSO2 API Manager end user registration from Mobile(Android and iOS) Application using google or facebook sign-in

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 API Manager 1.10 and WSO2 Identity server 5.1.0 for managing back end REST APIs which will be consumed by Android and iOS application.For a end user(Mobile App user) to access the APIs exposed,process followed is:-
1.User registers to WSO2 IS server using WSO2 SCIM create user API.
2.User request for access token which will be used for accessing the APIs.

We are planning to add Google and facebook sign in feature in our Mobile app which will help end user avoid user creation in WSO2 IS. Does WSO2 API Manager support this sort of implementation? if so,what are the cofiguration changes we need to do to our current setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can  achieve this using identity federation. IS will act as key manager as well as it can federate the authentication to facebook/google.
you can find how facebook can be configured to get access token in this blog[1]. Similarly you can add google for federation[2]

[1] http://nuwanzone.blogspot.com/2015/10/getting-access-tokens-for-wso2-api.html
[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Google

Comment: Jenananthan Thanks for the reference links! From what I have read, it looks like Mobile Application has to access WSO2 first,which will the redirect the user to Facebook or Google login. Upon Authorization,access token will be provided to user.

My Question:- Is it possible for Mobile App to login to Facebook or Google first and share the authcode with WSO2 for access token?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? Im having the same issue trying to connect fb with a native app and WSO2 IS :(