# WSO2 Identity Server- Should an end user of a Mobile application be persisted in User Store?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

We have a mobile application in android,we are using WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 and WSO2 Identity Server 5.2.0 for API management that will be consumed by Mobile Application. We have configured Identity server as Key store.

My question:- Is it necessary that we need to store end user details in user store for providing access token? Or the Mobile application can store the consumer key of the application that has subscribed to APIs needed by the mobile application i.e End user details are not stored in User store of Identity server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It completely depends on your requirement. You can either use Application Tokens or User Tokens. If you use Application Tokens, only the application developer being in the userstore is sufficient.

The drawback of this method is you can't identify which user really invoked which request.

Comment: Thanks Bhathiya! We want to use user tokens but Our setup allows end user to have social login. In such scenario how do we persist the user in userstore?  Could you please take time and give suggestion on:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763763/wso2-api-manager-end-user-registration-from-mobileandroid-and-ios-application/41763995#41763995

Comment: If you want to persist users in wso2 userstore, you can use JIT user provisioning.  https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+Just-In-Time+Provisioning+for+an+Identity+Provider